# Writing unit test case for nested function in javascript using mocha,sinon,chai

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js, sinon, sinon-chai

I want to write unit test case for fn1() following code:

```js
function add(a, b){
  const q = 5
  console.log(a)
  console.log(b)
  const c = a + b
  
  console.log(c)
  console.log('1')
  return c
}

function fn1(){
  let a = 5;
  let b = 6;
 let c = obj.add(a, b);
  console.log(a)
  console.log(b)
  console.log(c)
  console.log('1')
  return c;
}
```

And I want to pass different arguments to add(a, b) in fn1(). How can I do that using mocha, sinon, chai?

Comment: it's only "add(a, b)" intead "obj.add(a, b)"

Comment: where is `obj` defined? Why are you using `obj.add`? what's the goal here? what is the issue you're facing?

Answer (score 0):

You can use sinon stub, stub the add method and call [wrappedMethod](https://sinonjs.org/releases/latest/stubs/#stubwrappedmethod), which is a reference to original method; in order to force pass different arguments to add method.

But you need to structurize your code a little bit.

Here is the simple example to show you how to do it.

I create method add and method fn1 inside check object on file check.js

```
// File: check.js
const check = {
  add: (a, b) => {
    const q = 5
    console.log('add a:', a)
    console.log('add b:', b)
    const c = a + b
    console.log('add c:', c)
    console.log('add called');
    return c
  },
  fn1: () => {
    let a = 5;
    let b = 6;
    let c = check.add(a, b);
    console.log('fn1 a:', a);
    console.log('fn1 b:', b);
    console.log('fn1 c:', c);
    console.log('fn1 called');
    return c;
  },
};

module.exports = check;
```

And I create simple test file: check.spec.js

```
// File: check.spec.js
const sinon = require('sinon');
const check = require('./check');

describe('check', () => {
  it('pass different argument to add()', () => {
    sinon.stub(check, 'add').callsFake(
      function () {
        console.log('stub add:', arguments);
        // Change the arguments here:
        arguments['0'] = 7;
        // Call write method with modified arguments.
        return check.add.wrappedMethod.apply(this, arguments);
      }
    );
    check.fn1();
  });
});
```

I change the first argument a to 7. Here is the result when I run it at terminal:

```
$ npx mocha check.spec.js


  check
stub add: [Arguments] { '0': 5, '1': 6 }
add a: 7
add b: 6
add c: 13
add called
fn1 a: 5
fn1 b: 6
fn1 c: 13
fn1 called
    ✓ pass different argument to add()


  1 passing (4ms)
```